# VS Code 'code' cli returns SecCodeCheckValidity error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm encountering an issue with VS Code (Version: 1.86.1) where using the `code` command returns a SecCodeCheckValidity error

`[0219/153958.408585:ERROR:codesign_util.cc(108)] SecCodeCheckValidity: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "(null)" (-67062)`

The `code` command is successful but I would like to understand and resolve the error

It seems that SecCodeCheckValidity performs dynamic validation of signed code so I would expect that this shouldn't be an issue for VS Code on my macOS Monterey 12.3.1. The command ran without barking the error at me until it started about a week ago.

I attempted uninstalling `code` from Path and then reinstalling it but the error is still returned.

Answer (score 10):

Seems to be an instance of what's tracked in issue ticket [`code` cli prints a SecCodeCheckValidity error #204085](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204085). It's in the February release milestone, so hopefully it'll be fixed soon.

I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Someone found a workaround and shared it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204447#issue-2119960009) (**Warning**: *I don't know what this command does* or what implications it has, so I can't say if there's any cause for concern in running it. Apparently, it breaks auto-update. Use at your own risk):

> ```
> codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
> ```

Comment: This command breaks auto-update of VSCode. Currently, we have no choice but living with that error.